# cannot use kendo ui with cassette bundles in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, bundle, kendo-asp.net-mvc, cassette

I've created this bundle:

```
bundles.Add<ScriptBundle>("kendo-autocomplete", new string[] {
    "~/Scripts/Kendo/kendo.core.min.js",
    "~/Scripts/Kendo/kendo.aspnetmvc.min.js",
    "~/Scripts/Kendo/kendo.data.min.js",
    "~/Scripts/Kendo/kendo.list.min.js",
    "~/Scripts/Kendo/kendo.popup.min.js",
    "~/Scripts/Kendo/kendo.autocomplete.min.js"});
```

When debug is true, everything works fine and I can instantiate Kendo UI Autocomplete, but when debug is false, I get this error:

> TypeError: jQuery(...).kendoAutoComplete is not a function

I've already overridden `IConfiguration`, but nothing changed.

```
public class CustomCassetteServices : IConfiguration<TinyIoCContainer>
{
    public void Configure(TinyIoCContainer container)
    {
        var settings = new Microsoft.Ajax.Utilities.CodeSettings();
        settings.MinifyCode = true;
        settings.PreserveFunctionNames = true;
        settings.RemoveFunctionExpressionNames = false;
        settings.RemoveUnneededCode = true;
        settings.IgnoreAllErrors = true;
        settings.LocalRenaming = LocalRenaming.KeepAll;
        settings.ManualRenamesProperties = false;
        settings.OutputMode = OutputMode.SingleLine;
        settings.StrictMode = false;
        settings.CollapseToLiteral = false;
        container.Register<IJavaScriptMinifier>(new MicrosoftJavaScriptMinifier(settings));
    }
}
```

How can i fix this?

Comment: have you tried to remove the .min extension on your javascript file?. the rule of the bundling and minification is never use the .min extension for the javascript file

Comment: try including un minified (src) js files.